# Simple batch file not executing a short registry file file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hey so I have this code right here, but isn't working properly;

```
color B
echo Skikz b retsrating explor.exe
pause
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
start explorer.exe
color B
echo Settin' shit icon backz
pause
@echo off
rem  set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker  
REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "%~dp0\IconsBackup.reg"
color B
echo gain le xplorer rstrt
pause
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
start explorer.exe
pause
```

The restart command (both) work perfectly but the registry one is not, the `.reg` file is in the same folder as the bat file; it's weird because if I isolate the reg command it does work, just merging it with two restart tasks makes it not-to-work.

Note: I'm running the bat file 'as Administrator'

Greetings. Chron.

Comment: The `RegEdit` command requires to be 'Run as administrator'. Either do that or perhaps try, `Reg Import IconsBackup.reg` instead. If your script is writing to Local Machine, it may require to be run elevated too.

Comment: I'm running it as admin all the time, it's weird how i works when the command is on its own.

Comment: Where in your question area is that mentioned? _It helps when formulating a question, if you provide enough information that the comment area is not required for requesting it later._

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was logical to run a regedit command with administrative permissions, that'd why I slipped that away.